# how to Check the IP address of the Ethernet interface on the target device?

Tags: updates

I am new in embeddedlinux ,, also I want guidelines about how to run my first application on target ?

Comment: Ubunto version : 12.04

Comment: Please explain a bit more. What is your hardware? What is the target device?

Comment: Please edit your original question with the new information. We try to keep the comments to the minimum.

Answer (score 0):

I can update this if you give more information but the basic command to check network configuration is `ifconfig`:

```
$ /sbin/ifconfig wlan0
wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr c4:46:19:5f:dc:f5  
          inet addr:192.168.0.21  Bcast:192.168.255.255  Mask:255.255.0.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::c646:19ff:fe5f:dcf5/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:361918 errors:0 dropped:38 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:259496 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:213916434 (204.0 MiB)  TX bytes:59886866 (57.1 MiB)
```